# Comparação de menor valor em lista

Tags: python, array, python-3.x

Meu problema parece ser simples mas está bugando minha cabeça kkk, aí vai:

Quando comparo minha lista Valores para encontrar o menor valor, me retorna sempre 0, o que acontece sera? Segue cód abaixo.

obs: desconsiderar var tel_maior e menor.

```
menor_valor = 0    
maior_valor = 0
tel_maior = 0    
tel_menor = 0
if opcao == 3:
  for i in range(20):
    if i == 0:
      maior_valor = menor_valor = Valores[i]
    else:
      if Valores[i] > maior_valor:
         maior_valor = Valores[i]
        #tel_maior = Telefones[i]          
      if Valores[i] < menor_valor:
         menor_valor = Valores[i]
        #tel_menor = Telefones[i]
  print('A consulta com menor custo foi',menor_valor, ' com o telefone ',tel_menor, )
  print('O telefone do paciente com maior valor',maior_valor," com o telefone ",tel_maior)
```

Comment: Apesar de o código não ser muito pythonico e de haverem formas bem mais faceis de obter o mesmo resultado ele funciona. [Veja no Ideone o seu código a funcionar](https://ideone.com/64VtoX)

Answer (score 0):

Não há nada de errado com o código, talvez o erro esteja na sua lista?
Veja o código em execução com [este link gigantesco](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#code=import%20random%0AValores%20%3D%20%5Brandom.randint%280,100%29%20for%20i%20in%20range%2820%29%5D%0Aopcao%20%3D%203%0A%0Amenor_valor%20%3D%200%20%20%20%20%0Amaior_valor%20%3D%200%0Atel_maior%20%3D%200%20%20%20%20%0Atel_menor%20%3D%200%0Aif%20opcao%20%3D%3D%203%3A%0A%20%20for%20i%20in%20range%2820%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20i%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20maior_valor%20%3D%20menor_valor%20%3D%20Valores%5Bi%5D%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20Valores%5Bi%5D%20%3E%20maior_valor%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20maior_valor%20%3D%20Valores%5Bi%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23tel_maior%20%3D%20Telefones%5Bi%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20Valores%5Bi%5D%20%3C%20menor_valor%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20menor_valor%20%3D%20Valores%5Bi%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23tel_menor%20%3D%20Telefones%5Bi%5D%0A%20%20print%28'A%20consulta%20com%20menor%20custo%20foi',menor_valor,%20'%20com%20o%20telefone%20',tel_menor,%20%29%0A%20%20print%28'O%20telefone%20do%20paciente%20com%20maior%20valor',maior_valor,%22%20com%20o%20telefone%20%22,tel_maior%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=116&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false):

**Edit**

Você também pode pegar o maior e menor valor simplesmente usando

```
menor_valor = min(Valores)
maior_valor = max(Valores)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Medicos = [0] * 20
Hiro = [0] * 10
Massao = [0] * 10
Telefones = [0] * 20
Horarios = [0] * 20
Valores = [0] * 20
proxlivre = 0
soma1 = 0
soma2 = 0
opcao = 0
while opcao != 5:
    print("Valores", Valores)

```
print('Menu')
print('Opção 1 - Agenda horario')
print('Opção 2 - Contagem de Atendimento')
print('Opção 3 - Atendimento mais caro e mais barato')
print('Opção 4 - Lista de agendamentos')
print('Opção 5 - Sair')
print('Digite opção desejada')
opcao = int(input())
if opcao == 5:
    exit()
elif opcao == 6 or opcao == 7 or opcao == 8 or opcao == 9:
    print('opção inválida')

if opcao == 1:

    repete = True
    while (repete):
        novo_tel = int(input("Digite telfone do paciente"))
        med = int(input("Digite 1 - Hiro ou 2 - Massao "))
        print("Digite horario do atendimento")
        nova_hora = int(input())
        achei = False
        for j in range(20):
            if nova_hora == Horarios[j] and med == Medicos[j]:
                print("horario duplicado")
                achei = True
                repete = True
                break
        if not achei:
            repete = False
    Horarios[proxlivre] = nova_hora
    Medicos[proxlivre] = med
    Telefones[proxlivre] = novo_tel
    if med == 1:
        Hiro[proxlivre] = nova_hora
    elif med == 2:
        Massao[proxlivre] = nova_hora
    print('informe o valor da consulta')
    if med == 1:
        preço1 = float(input())
        Valores[proxlivre] = preço1
        soma1 = soma1 + preço1
    if med == 2:
        preço2 = float(input())
        Valores[proxlivre] = preço2
        soma2 = soma2 + preço2
    proxlivre += 1
conta_Hiro = 0
conta_Massao = 0
if opcao == 2:
    for i in range(20):
        if Medicos[i] == 1:
            conta_Hiro += 1
        elif Medicos[i] == 2:
            conta_Massao += 1

    print('o numero de consultas para o médico Hiro é {}'.format(conta_Hiro))
    print('o numero de consultas para o médico Massao é {}'.format(conta_Massao))


menor_valor = 0
maior_valor = 0
tel_maior = 0
tel_menor = 0
if opcao == 3:
    for i in range(20):
        if Valores[i] > maior_valor:
            maior_valor = Valores[i]
            tel_maior = Telefones[i]

        if i == 0:
            menor_valor = Valores[i]
        else:
            if menor_valor > Valores[i]:
               menor_valor = Valores[i]
               tel_menor = Telefones[i]

    print('A consulta com menor custo foi', menor_valor, ' com o telefone ', tel_menor)
    print('O telefone do paciente com maior valor', maior_valor, " com o telefone ", tel_maior)

if opcao == 4:
    for i in range(20):
        if Medicos[i] == 1:
            soma_hiro = soma1
        elif Medicos[i] == 2:
            soma_massao = soma2
    print(
        'O valor das consultas do Médico Hiro é de R$ {} e do Médico Massao é R$ {}'.format(soma_hiro, soma_massao))`
```

Ok! Você tem razão, sempre retorna zero pq declarei minha lista Valores = [0] * 20, sendo assim irá deixar de retornar zero somente se eu preencher a lista toda, nos  testes apenas colocava 5 valores no máximo. Preciso utilizar aquela forma de comparação com if e else pois após resolver este entrave do retorno igual a 0, preciso informar o telefone do numero maior e menor (lista valores). Daí to com dificuldade de fazer isso utilizando min e max. O código inteiro vai abaixo.